# Shared Observable Error Handling Issue

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the Observable returned from angular2 http.get() method. My relevant code is here...

```
let observable = this.http.get(this.url)
if (this.share) {
  observable = observable.share();
}

if (this.firstHandle) {
  observable.subscribe(result => {
    this.result = result._body;
  },
  err => {
    this.error = err;
  });
} else {
  observable.subscribe(result => {
    this.result = result._body;
  });
}

observable.subscribe(result => {
  this.result2 = result._body
},
err => {
  this.error2 = err;
})
```

If **this.share** is true and **this.firstHandle** is false then the above code doesn't behave as I would expect. The error is not handled in the second subscribe call. All other cases behave as I expect. Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9D2gT1q6o1FWtGBSkuAq) showing the behavior. Notice that the last case does not show the error from a bad call. Just trying to understand the reason for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning this myself.  I was looking at the [share method in the RxJS library](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) and it looks like the first time you call subscribe is the only time it actually creates a new subscription. The second time you call subscribe it just shares the data and doesn't actually make a new subscription. So I think that means it wouldn't see the error handling parameter defined in your second subscription.

Comment: But that's the weird thing. It **does** see it **if** I handle the error in the first subscribe but **doesn't** if I don't. It seems to me that the logic they used was if your first subscriber is not interested in the error than no other subscriber will be either. I don't understand that.

Comment: I think share might have a different purpose in RxJS.  I think the effect you are looking for might be creating a Connectable Observable and using the Publish operator on it. Again I am in the same boat of trying to wrap my head around all of the new stuff Angular 2.